# After enabling textIsSelectable to true my text stops swiping when i SWIPE with finger

Tags: java, android, ios

After setting textIsSelectable to true, the text stops swiping, but any other spot I touch apart from the text swipes by using the finger. whats wrong? I want my text to swipe after enabling textisselectable to true, I want my users to copy to clipbord and also swipe. but when i remove the textIsSelectable set to true the pages swipes easily. whats is wrong ? please any suggested help? I would be grateful

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="my favorite Quotes" />


<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dip"
    android:background="#FF312828"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/Jim_Rohn"
            android:textColor="#FFC7C7EA"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold">
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/jimrohn" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/ludwig_wittgenstein"
            android:textColor="#FFC7C7EA"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold">
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ludwigwittgenstein" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and the java

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Favorite Quotes");
    TextView textView = (TextView) v;
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(textView.getText());
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since setting the value of textIsSelectable (to `true`) also sets the flags `focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode`, `clickable`, and `longClickable` to `true`. So in your case, you'd want to re-set these other flags manually to their default values or the values you had set in them previously. My suggestion would be to set all of them to `false`, especially those that you did not set to any value before.
So you could this in code:

```
...
TextView textView = (TextView) v; 
v.setClickable(false);
v.setLongClickable(false);
```

I hope this helps, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your kind respond ishmaelMakitla but it didn't help, if you can help me further.

Comment: Please try adding `v.focusableInTouchMode(false);` and `v.focusable(false);` - let me know this helps.

Comment: my vieflipper is controlled from anim           <set 
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate                                                   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
            // when user first touches the screen to swap
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                lastX = touchevent.getX();
                break;
            }
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>